# Seeking an English-language proof of "Petersen’s classic decomposition theorem": $2r$-regular graphs can be decomposed into $r$ disjoint $2$-factors.

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

From [this paper](http://www1.combinatorics.org/Volume_12/Abstracts/v12i1n23.html) we find the quote:

> **Lemma 1** (Petersen [2]) Every $2r$-regular graph can be decomposed into $r$ disjoint $2$-factors.

They described it as "Petersen’s classic decomposition theorem about regular graphs of even degree".  The reference [2] is:

> J. Petersen, *Die Theorie der Regularen Graphen*, Acta Math. 15 (1891), 193-220.

I don't have access to this paper, nor would I think it would do me much good, since the title suggests it's not in English.

> **Question**:  Where else can I find an English language proof of this result?

Comment: Here is a link to the article: J. Petersen, [Die Theorie der regulären Graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02392606) which is indeed in German.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this suits you since the *disjoint* condition is omitted but in

- Laszlo Lovász; Combinatorial Problems and Exercises (2nd edition). North-Holland, Amsterdam (page 61. exercise 40.)

there is the following exercise (with hints and proofs included)

> Every $2r$ regular graph is the union of $r$ 2-factors.

I am not sure if the *disjoint* part of your claim is just part of a different definition of factors than the one used in Lovász or if there is a way to modify the proof there to show this additional condition.

Comment: Hmm... I think you get the "disjoint" property for free -- if they weren't disjoint, the union wouldn't be a $2r$-regular graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Reinhard Diestel's "Graph Theory" textbook (Corollary 2.1.5 in the 4th edition).